# How to send coordinates from javascript file to flask server to put in DB?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a simple flask app that takes a comment written by a user via a textarea, and posts it in the database under the 'content' column of my database 'Comments':

```
            <div class="row">
                <form action="." method="POST">
                    <textarea name="contents" placeholder="Enter a comment" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Post comment">
                </form>
            </div>
```

And then on the server:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("bulletin.html", comments=Comment.query.filter(Comment.content != ''))

    comment = Comment(content=request.form["contents"])
    db.session.add(comment)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Lets say I have two variables, latitude and longitude in javascript. How can I send those variables to my flask server to store in the same database table? (Assuming I have created the Latitude and Longitude columns in my table)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First setup python to accept such information. Create an endpoint for coords to be posted to

```python
@app.route("/coords/<x>/<y>", methods=["POST"])
  def coords(x, y):
    # Have the code here to save to which ever database you use
```

Then have javascript send a post request to that URL.
In your example you use a form so take usage of the HTML action tag to post to a specific URL

Comment: I was more so wondering how I can attach the latitude and longitude to the 'Comment' object as the 'Comment' Object is a model that has a latitude and longitude attribute to it, and it is a mapping to a table. (So the comment table has latitude and longitude columns)